# Extract string using stringr

Tags: regex, r

I have a string `"BTL_OTM_TLS_TTL_ACQ_0.0.0|Fixed"` from where I want to extract `"BTL_OTM_TLS_TTL_ACQ"`.

However I am getting `"BTL_OTM_TLS_TTL_ACQ" "|"`. I have used stringr and I have provided the code below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
> k
[1] "BTL_OTM_TLS_TTL_ACQ_0.0.0|Fixed"
> str_extract(k, "(_)[0-9](.)+")
[1] "_0.0.0|Fixed"
> strsplit(as.character(k),str_extract(as.character(k),"(_)[0-9](.)+"))
[[1]]
[1] "BTL_OTM_TLS_TTL_ACQ" "|"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `sub` from `base R`

```
 sub('_\\d.*', '', k)
 #[1] "BTL_OTM_TLS_TTL_ACQ"
```

Or using `lookarounds` with `str_extract`

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(k, perl('.*(?=_[0-9])'))
 #[1] "BTL_OTM_TLS_TTL_ACQ"
```

Or

```
strsplit(k, '_[0-9]+.*$')[[1]]
#[1] "BTL_OTM_TLS_TTL_ACQ"
```

#### Update

If we need to extract `0.0.0`, one option is

```
gsub('^[^0-9]*|\\|.*$', '', k)
#[1] "0.0.0"
```

#### data

```
k <- "BTL_OTM_TLS_TTL_ACQ_0.0.0|Fixed"
```

Comment: is there any way I can extract 0.0.0 out of the expression??

Comment: Try `gsub('^[^0-9]*|\\|.*$', '', k)#[1] "0.0.0"`